# Magento 2 : How be able to export csv from admin as nonadministrator?

Tags: magento2, csv, export, permissions

If you  logged in as nonadministrator and try to export any CSV from grid level it will show access denied
this issue is not there in 2.1.0 onwards but exists in 2.0.8 and below

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

need to create  acl file in one of your custom module 
and logged in as super admin and select roles for the respective user

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Ui::exportToCsv" title="Export To CSV" sortOrder="11" />
                <resource id="Magento_Ui::exportToXml" title="Export To XML" sortOrder="12" />
                <resource id="Magento_Swatches::iframe" title="Swatch Upload Images" sortOrder="13" />
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>

</config>
```

above code will give permission for export csv , xml and also uploading image for swatch attributes